svg mask is broken with <use>
I created a simple Snippet to demonstrate a different behavior between Chrome/Safari and Firefox.


<svg style="display:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="foo">     
    <mask id="mask1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="white" />
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" mask="url(#mask1)" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use href="#foo"/>
</svg>




Do you have any idea how to fix this?
expected: half of the square is red (works in Firefox)
received: the whole square is red
hint: Without the <use> technic, Chrome has no problem with the mask.

You should hide your svg containing the mask definition e.g via position:absolute;width:0; height:0 (see codepen). Display none disables the mask. Unfortunately masks or clipPaths as well as gradients can cause problems in some browsers when defined in symbols. Things get worse when using external svg use references

you should report Chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker

@herrstrietzel thank you for the hint. I found a very old chrome bug describing my problem https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40134477

Is it a bug?!? Remove the display:none


<svg style="display:initial" width=0 height=0 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="foo">     
    <mask id="mask1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="white" />
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" mask="url(#mask1)" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use href="#foo"/>
</svg>




Alternative, use a native Web Component
Since <symbol> requires a unique ID all you can use use for is to display the same thing.
A native Web Component might be more powerful:


<my-square></my-square>
<my-square></my-square>
<my-square fill="blue"></my-square>

<style>
  my-square { width:160px }
</style>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-square",class extends HTMLElement{
    connectedCallback() {
      this.style.display = "inline-block";
      this.innerHTML = `
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <mask id="mask1">
           <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="white" />
          </mask>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" 
                fill="${this.getAttribute("fill")||"red"}" mask="url(#mask1)" />
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black" />
        </svg>`
    }
  })
</script>




Yes, without display:none it is working.
In my real implementation, my symbol is not part of the DOM. the svg is an external file and without a display:none
It seems that Chrome omits masks, gradients and other fancy stuff.
